# mysql_num_rows() returning 0

Tags: php, mysql

My $result variable will equal to "Resource id #4" when program executes. 
 Which clearly means that my mysql_query() was successfully executed.
 But when I call in mysql_num_rows($result), I always get back 0. Although a row does exist, I keep getting a value of 0. Why?

```
if (isset($_POST["user"]) && isset($_POST["pass"]))
{
    // prepare SQL
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username='%s' AND password=PASSWORD('%s')",
                   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user"]),
                   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pass"]));

    // execute query
    $result = mysql_query($sql);


    if ($result === false)
        die("Could not query database");


    $numOfRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Did you try printing `$sql` and debug it? Maybe your user and pass values contain code that is being escaped by `mysql_real_escape_string`. Also, try to use `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead of the deprecated `MySQL` library (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: fyi the `mysql_*` are deprecated.

Comment: Is "1" referring to a column name? That doesn't mean "get one row", a list of column names you wish to retrieve the values from should come after `SELECT`

Comment: @Diamondo25 but if my code is being escaped by mysql_real_escape_string, then wouldn't $result = false? Because remember, the query is successful and does return a value which is resource id #4

Comment: @ChrisBrown - `SELECT 1` is perfectly valid syntax if you don't want to return data from a query, but only test for the existence of a record.... it will return a numeric "1" (in a column called "1" for every record that is found matching the WHERE clause, and a count of the resultset (e.g. mysql_num_rows()) will give a 1 (or more) or a 0 for found or not found

Comment: @RoyKesserwani An error in your query returns `false` with `mysql_query`. If there are no rows that matched your `WHERE` statement, it will just finish but without any rows.

Comment: @MarkBaker Pretty embarrassing that I didn't even know that..

Comment: Mark Baker is absolutely correct, it's perfectly valid to return a literal in the SELECT list, though I typically assign an alias to the literal, i.e. `SELECT 1 AS one FROM ...`; and I typically add a `LIMIT 1` clause to end of the query, if my intent is to test for the existence of at least one row, and I don't care how many rows match. Also, I don't use the **`=== false`** pattern to test for a query error; I typically use **`if (!$result)`**.

Comment: @ChrisBrown - not so embarrassing, it's not that intuitive.... you're only likely to know it if you've encountered it before

Comment: none of you guys are helping me out with my issue

Comment: @RoyKesserwani I would help you, but I no longer support questions using `mysql_*`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing obviously wrong with your code.

The most obvious explanation is that the query being submitted to the database is not returning any rows.

I recommend you add some rudimentary debugging: echo (or vardump or printf) the value of the SQL text **`$sql`** prior to submitting it to the database.

Verify that the SQL text is what you expect to be submitted to the database, and that this query returns a row.

As another step in debugging, I recommend you actually fetch the rows from the resultset, and display the returned rows.

---

I typically assign an alias to literals in the SELECT list, e.g.

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM ...
```

But I don't think this would really cause an issue with the mysql_num_rows.

---

I believe earlier versions of PHP defaulted to having "magic quotes" feature being turned (automatically running an addslashes function on strings); echoing out the generated SQL would show if "double escaping" was a problem or not.

---

**Addendum**

An obligatory note here that the **mysql_** interface is DEPRECATED, and new development should make use of one of the (much improved) replacements: **mysqli** or **PDO**.